# Activating a menu in eclips plugin

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, plugins

I created a menu (on the top bar near file edit ... ) in an eclipse plugin project in plugin.xml. Now I want to activate and inactivate the menu based on the value of a boolean variable in one of my java classes. I don't know how to pass the Boolean variable from the Java class into the .xml plugin file.

Comment: What do you mean by 'activate'? Is this making it visible? Making it enabled? Which extension point are you using to declare the menu?

Comment: It looks like you need a [property tester](https://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fexpressions%2FPropertyTester.html)

Comment: What I mean by activating is making it clickable.

Comment: `code` <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers"> <handler commandId="menu1" class="Proj1.Mypackage.myclass"> <enabledWhen> <with variable="mypackage.food.cooked"> <!-- cooked is a boolean variable in food class --> <equals value="true"> </equals> </with> </enabledWhen> </handler> </extension>  `code`